# Deploy surface sdk2 application on a tablet

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, pixelsense

I have developed a surface application(wpf) using visual studio 2010--> suface v2-->surface application(WPF).

Now i want to test the application in tablet. I tried on Windows rt and 8. but none are compatible.

What is the tablet specification i require for this scenario. Or how should I Deploy the application.

One more question how we can specify the resolution for devises. ie samsung sur40 has a larger screen and tablet small. how can we adjust this in app. whether it is needed such adjustments.
Name Spaces am using are,

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Microsoft.Surface;
using Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WPF is a Windows-based technology. It only runs in desktop-based Windows. I'm not aware of any tablet computer that can run that.

Comment: Show us the Namespaces inserted when you created your project. The WPF namespace is `System.Windows`. In 2011 Microsoft rebranded the old Surface hardware as "PixelSense", but the namespace remained `Surface`. PixelSense requires special hardware and will not run on desktops nor tablets.

Comment: I have developed the app in my Local PC with Windows 7(32 bit).

namespace SurfaceApplicationDemo
{
   
    public partial class SurfaceWindow1 : SurfaceWindow
    {
        
        public SurfaceWindow1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AllowDrop = true;
            Background = Brushes.Transparent;            
            AddWindowAvailabilityHandlers();
            
            }
:
:

Comment: @Anish, those are class names you made up. We need to know the System namespaces you used; they are at the top of your file. And put them in the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are several Win 8 Tablets that are available that run full windows 8 and will run all apps that Windows 7 can run. I am using an Acer W510-1666 to run my WPF apps.

I hope this helps

Comment: +1 I really didn't know that. And its AWESOME news. Now we have THE POWER of WPF and `portability` combined!!!

Comment: application developed with visual studio surface sdk2 in not working in Windows 8 tablet. Does the Tablet need any additional hardware or software.

My application is just a demo purpose one with few controls such a scatter view and surface buttons.

application got install but not functioning button clicks.

i tried sample application with sdk2 such as Scatter puzzle but it is not even running.

What is the actual Cause of all these mishapps. Am new to surface application development.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more details about how your app is failing:
   - Are you getting any error messages? If so, what are they?
   - Are you including all the necessary libraries (especially Surface related libraries)?

Answer (score 1):

To run a Pixelsense application on a Windows 8 system (Pro version) you need to install the Surface Runtime. To capture multitouch input make sure the application runs in a normal window, not a SurfaceWindow.